# QSqlQuery pickle serialize

Tags: pyqt5, pickle, qsqlquery

I'm trying to set up a client server TCP program where the server has access to a MySQL database. The issue is how to send a QSqlQuery back from the server to the client. The communication server client is through struct data and pickle and I'm getting the expected exception "TypeError cannot pickle QSqlQuery object." I tried to create a custom class "class MyQuery(QSqlQuery)" but I could not make it work. Actually I cannot understand the “Pickling Class Instances” from the” https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html” documentation. Finally I also looked into QNetworkAccessManager that does'nt seam to throw any additional possibility or advantage over socketserver.
The only work around I could figure out was to save the query values in a List and send the list back to the client.

Can somebody help me out. Is it possible to serialize a QSqlQuery? If so, how?. Is there a better way to send a QSqlQuery over a network?

Comment: Although I think I have a solution to your background problem (I have not yet implemented it) I'm curious: MySQL supports remote connection, why not use that feature?

Comment: I was hoping this approach to be more efficient. Would it? You're right. It'll work with MySQL remote connection.